# html form submit button

Tags: html, forms

I have a form and when the form is loaded through a browser, I want it to submit the data automatically.

The problem is I wrote a PHP script that will submit it all fine on a test form. My problem is the server I'm trying to submit the data to named the button "submit".

Here is the example form:

```
<html>

<head>
</head>

<form  action="http://www.example.com/post.php"  method="post">
    <input type="text" name="input1" value="test1"  />
    <input type="text" name="input2" value="test2"  />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.forms[0].action="submit"
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

The person that created the form on the other server named it "submit". Is there a workaround until they fix it?

Here is a example of the person's form

```
<html>

<head>
</head>

<form  action="http://www.example.com/post.php"  method="post">
    <input type="text" name="input1" value="test1"  />
    <input type="text" name="input2" value="test2"  />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" value="Send Data" />
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is a pretty localized question. Generally on StackOverflow, it's preferred that questions be phrased in such a way that they can apply to the developer community at large and not just to a specific problem that you're having.

Comment: The HTML is not well formed. The starting `body` tag is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to submit the form? Then simply use its `submit()` method:

```
document.forms[0].submit();
```

If the server expects `submit` to be POSTed, i.e. the button being clicked, you can simply trigger the `click()` event of the button. Since you cannot access it using its name, I'd use jQuery for it:

```
$('input[name="submit"]').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<form  action="http://www.example.com/post.php"  method="post">
<input type="text" name="input1" value="test1"  />
<input type="text" name="input2" value="test2"  />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.forms[0].action="submit"
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<form name="MyForm" action="http://www.example.com/post.php"  method="post">
<input type="text" name="input1" value="test1"  />
<input type="text" name="input2" value="test2"  />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.MyForm.submit();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It will try to submit the data but doesn't recognize anything on the server side like nothing was submitted.

Comment: It would be better if it included the missing starting `body` tag is .

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the input element has name="submit" and type="submit". They are different things.

So you can also create the same behavior easily.

Comment: Create the same behavior how exactly? Can you elaborate? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10312042/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).